# Doing complex operation on a dataframe depending on a column value in R

Tags: r

First of all I apologies for bad English.

I have a dataframe of 31 columns and more than 120k rows of hourly measurements that looks like this:

| DateTime | Ethane | Ethene | [...] | Season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008-01-01 01:00:00 | 10.81 | 1.47 | [...] | DJF_2008 |
| 2008-01-01 02:00:00 | 10.31 | 1.13 | [...] | DJF_2008 |

...

What i'm trying to do is to calculate the log10 of each measurements (this is the easy part) and then I'm trying to calculate the % of data that are superior to the mean + 4 standard deviation or inferior to the mean - 4 standard deviation for each compounds for each season.

In other words, what i'm trying to do is to:

-calculate the mean + 4 standard deviation depending on the season for each compound

-calculate the mean - 4 standard deviation depending on the season for each compound

-calculate the number of measurements superior to the mean + 4 standard deviation for each compound each season

-calculate the number of measurements inferior to the mean - 4 standard deviation

-doing the sum of measurements superior to the mean + 4sd + inferior to the mean -4sd for each compound each season

-having the percentage (by doing the (sum value) / (length of of the season) for each compound each season.

I tried the group_by function. It works very well to have the mean + 4 SD and the mean - 4 SD for each compound each season (see the code bellow) but I'm stucked with several problems.

```
LogC <- log10(My_dataset[,2:30])
LogC$Date_Time <- My_dataset$DateTime #this line and 3 next ones are not very usefull, don't take a lot of care on it
LogC$Season <- My_dataset$Season
LogC <- LogC[,c(30,1:31)]
LogC <- LogC[,-c(31)]

Lim_max <- LogC %>%
  group_by (Season) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-Date_Time),funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE) + 4 * sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
Lim_max <- Lim_max %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(is.nan(.), NA, .))

Lim_min <- LogC %>%
  group_by (Season) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-Date_Time),funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE) - 4 * sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
Lim_min <- Lim_min %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(is.nan(.), NA, .))
```

First, dataframe obtained thanks to group_by are obviously not the same length than the initial dataframe.

I was thinking of adding these results on rows at the end of the dataframe but I have 58 rows of mean + 4SD and 58 rows of mean - 4SD. It would be a mess in my opinion.

I was also thinking on a function containing multiple function to apply during the group_by to have all kind of calculation done directly with the group_by but to be honest I really have no idea on how to proceed to create such a function.

What I would like in the end is a new dataframe with each column corresponding to each compounds and each row to each season and results are the percentage as mention above (it's very low, under 1% but it is percentage, they are expected to be very low) like this:

| Season | Ethane | Ethene | [...] | 124TMB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DJF_2008 | 0.07 | 0.41 | [...] | 0.35 |
| MAM_2008 | 0.12 | 0.18 | [...] | 0.27 |

Thank you for the solution you can propose to this problem.